# chrome har file generation

Tags: google-chrome, centos, har

I'm currently using phantomjs to jenerate HAR files. But it sometimes hangup therefor I'm trying to use Chrome to do it. i install it and also installed [chrome-har-capturer](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-har-capturer) to do the job for me.

But when i tried to execute

```
chrome-har-capturer -o out.har https://github.com
```

it false saying

```
cannot connect to chrome
error : connect ECONNREFUSED
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm missing...I'm on centos(64)VPS and chrome latest stable version

Answer (score 0):

From my expirience, I think the problem is Chrome not opening properly. As you are using a VPS, it doesn't have a windowing environment, so you also need to make sure you have Xvfb installed to provide virtual visual buffer. You can do so using

```
yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb
```

Then use

```
xvfb-run google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 > /dev/null &
```

Which should start google chrome in the background. If everything works as it is supposed to, now you should have no problem using you command to capture har file.

To make sure chrome is running, use

```
ps -aux|grep google-chrome
```

Once chrome is running normally you can then use

```
chrome-har-capturer -o out.har https://github.com
```

Comment: still cannot connect to chrome
error : connect ECONNREFUSED

Comment: Referring to [this](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-har-capturer/issues/4) issue, you might need to update your Node.